# Unsubscribe from Observable stopping the http call

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

There is an issue I'm facing. Not sure if it is working as expected.

```
  startTimerSubscription(){
    this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    let subscription = this._testService.getTimerData().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    this.timerSubscription.add(subscription);
  }
```

Whenever I'm calling the function, the data is never subscribed. i.e there is no console print of the data.

my test service has `getTimerData()` defined as:

```
getTimerData(){
    return timer(0,10000).pipe(switchMap(()=> {
      return of(this.testData);
    }));
  }
```

Can someone explain this behaviour to me? I'm unsubscribing the data before subscribing it. Shouldn't the data be logged every 10 seconds?

I tried using `interval` operator and the result is the same.

I have also created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subscription-issue)

Thanks in advance

Comment: why the downvote ? is this not a valid question ? if this is a duplicate then please help me out by posting the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `.unsubscribe()` before adding any subscription with `.add()`.

When you call `.unsubscribe()` it marks the Subscription object as "closed" and when you try adding any other subscription it unsubscribes that as well because the "parent" subscription is "closed" already.

So you won't see any console output because `timer()` emits asynchronously and you in fact unsubscribe before it even emit anything. In contrast, `startWith` operator emits immediately on subscription.

These are the particular lines

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L62
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L140

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `add` on a subscription for itself. Here is a [working solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subscription-issue-ha4ffa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Instead of using `add` method, I simply assign subscriptions to your class members.

```
this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
this.timerSubscription = this._testService.getTimerData().subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});

------

this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
this.intervalSubscription = this._testService.getIntervalData().subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`add` method gets `TearDownLogic` which will be used when the subscription is destroyed. For example, you may have other `Subscription`s to be destroyed with this one, so you can add it.

> add(teardown: TeardownLogic): Subscription
>
> Adds a tear down to be called during the unsubscribe() of this
>   Subscription.

For more info, check the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-method-add)